# I want to pull specific data from a text file through python

Tags: python

I have a text file which contains data like given below:

```
########### PLURIMEDIA APP1 REPORT of Date 2020-03-17 10:55:43 #################
Number of events in EPG:- 105  for channel:- 229  for date:- 20200317
Number of events in EPG:- 38  for channel:- 526  for date:- 20200317
Number of events in EPG:- 105  for channel:- 229  for date:- 20200318
Number of events in EPG:- 46  for channel:- 526  for date:- 20200318
Number of events in EPG:- 128  for channel:- 229  for date:- 20200319
Number of events in EPG:- 46  for channel:- 526  for date:- 20200319
Number of events in EPG:- 128  for channel:- 229  for date:- 20200320
Number of events in EPG:- 46  for channel:- 526  for date:- 20200320
Number of events in EPG:- 102  for channel:- 229  for date:- 20200321
Number of events in EPG:- 26  for channel:- 526  for date:- 20200321
Number of events in EPG:- 103  for channel:- 229  for date:- 20200322
Number of events in EPG:- 27  for channel:- 526  for date:- 20200322
Number of events in EPG:- 128  for channel:- 229  for date:- 20200323
Number of events in EPG:- 46  for channel:- 526  for date:- 20200323
Number of events in EPG:- 24  for channel:- 229  for date:- 20200324
Number of events in EPG:- 8  for channel:- 526  for date:- 20200324
Number of images in EPG :- 112  for channel:- 229  for date:- 20200317
Number of images in EPG :- 10  for channel:- 526  for date:- 20200317
Number of images in EPG :- 109  for channel:- 229  for date:- 20200318
Number of images in EPG :- 11  for channel:- 526  for date:- 20200318
Number of images in EPG :- 132  for channel:- 229  for date:- 20200319
```

I want (Number of events in **Epg :-105**)

This data is from the text file.

Comment: Did you try something so far?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to make your question better. Questions seeking code and debugging help are not encouraged. Please show the effort you have put in and then ask for help in problems faced, which is a better approach. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get the rows that contain **Epg :-105** then this is the code:

```
file1 = open('myfile.txt', 'r') #read the txt file
Lines = file1.readlines() # read line by line

for line in Lines:
    if 'EPG:- 105' in line: # check for each line if it contains 'Epg :-105'
        print(line.strip()) # do whatever you want to do with those lines
```

You can then store those rows in a list instead of printing them

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't clearly specify if you want the number of images data as well as the number of events data to be displayed.

```
import re
fh = open('file.txt')

for line in fh:
    line = line.rstrip()
    stuff = re.findall('Number of events in EPG:- [0-9]+', line)
    if len(stuff) == 0:
        continue
    else:
        print(stuff[0])
```

The above code has been used to determine the Number of events data.

To find both the number of events and the number of images data.
Use the snippet given below.

```
import re
fh = open('file.txt')

for line in fh:
    line = line.rstrip()
    stuff = re.findall('Number of events in EPG:- [0-9]+', line)
    if len(stuff) == 0:
        stuff = re.findall('Number of images in EPG :- [0-9]+', line)
        if len(stuff) == 0:
            continue
        else:
            print(stuff[0])
    else:
        print(stuff[0])
```

The above code snippets use the knowledge of regular expressions.